# Twitter API V2 in python

Tags: api, twitterapi-python

I want to post text with media on my twitter account by using twitter api v2 with python code
I have code below to avoid
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve

that asks to subscribe basic access but I want free one
If I write this code, everything is ok but how can i post media as well?

```
python
import tweepy
client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key="",
                    consumer_secret="",
                    access_token="",
                    access_token_secret="")
# only text
response = client.create_tweet(text='hello world')
```